# Referencing SysV init scripts as systemd unit file dependency

Tags: linux, systemd

Running Ubuntu 16.04. I've installed Apache2 from package, which installed a SysV init script at `/etc/init.d/apache2` and a Systemd unit file config at `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/apache2-systemd.conf`.

Now I want to create a custom target that starts apache2 (among other things -- this is to create a dev environment that I can easily spin up and take down on a low-resource computer). I've created a target unit file at `/etc/systemd/system/my-dev-env.target` and a "wants" directory at `/etc/systemd/system/my-dev-env.target.wants`. I've put links to the other systemd unit files in `my-dev-env.target.wants` and they all work fine, but I can't figure out how to tell systemd that I also want apache in there. I tried linking to the `.conf` file, but it didn't work (nor did it throw any explicit errors).

Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/apache2-systemd.conf` is a [drop-in](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), so linking to that won't work.

Since apache2 is a good old SysV init script, you'll need to link to the `/etc/init.d/apache2` script. Make sure to name your link with a .service suffix or systemd won't pick it up. Ex. `ln -s /etc/init.d/apache2 /etc/systemd/system/my-dev-env.target.wants/apache2.service`

Comment: Ha! I never even thought just link to the SysV init file. Seems to work like a charm. (For future readers, remember to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after linking.)